# Check how long untill being logged off in win7 (from cmd)?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, shutdown, cmd.exe

When I was young, I learned a quick way to set a timer to turn off my computer

```
shutdown -f -s -t 3600
```

That would give me 1 hour until log off and shutdown.

I remember in windows xp, there would be a timer counting down. But win7 only shows a notice for a very short period of time. Then disappears.

I know I can just cancel it and then reset if needed.
But how can I check how much time is left after a while?

Additionally, what would be the "modern" code to do this in Powershell?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/414314/time-left-before-scheduled-shutdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Check how long until being logged off in win7 (from cmd)?**
>
> set a timer to turn off my computer
>
> `shutdown -f -s -t 3600`
>
> 1. how can I check how much time is left after a while?
> 2. what would be the "modern" code to do this in Powershell?

*Seems like a two question post so I'll answer the second one since someone pointed out the first questions has been asked and answered with that reference here [Time Left Before Scheduled Shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/414314/time-left-before-scheduled-shutdown) or perhaps here as well [Detecting a Windows Shutdown Command](https://superuser.com/questions/590434/detecting-if-a-windows-shutdown-command-has-been-issued)*

---

### **Shutdown One or More Machines with PowerShell (locally or remotely)**

Below are modern PowerShell equivelant commands as you requested for the `SHUTDOWN` command otherwise.

Just plug in your PC name (or array of names) after the `-ComputerName` paramater with double quotes around each, separated by commas, and let it do the rest.

**Single Computer Shutdown**

`Stop-Computer -ComputerName "<PC Name>" -Force`

**Single Computer Shutdown**

`Stop-Computer -ComputerName "<PC Name1>","<PC Name2>","<PC Name3>" -Force`

**Resources and Further Research and Reading**

- [Stop-Computer](http://ss64.com/ps/stop-computer.html)
- [TechNet Scripting Guy Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/04/01/scripting-wife-uses-powershell-to-shut-down-computers.aspx)
- [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849839.aspx)